# aws-azure-login don't reconize my default region

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, command-line-interface

When I try to connect with `aws-azure-login` i get this error:

```
UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `sts.amazonaws.com' at port `undefined'. This service may not be available in the `us-east-1' region.
    at Request.ENOTFOUND_ERROR (C:\Users\500000198\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-azure-login\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js:529:46)
    at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\500000198\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-azure-login\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (C:\Users\500000198\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-azure-login\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (C:\Users\500000198\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-azure-login\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:686:14)
    at error (C:\Users\500000198\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-azure-login\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js:361:22)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\500000198\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-azure-login\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\http\node.js:99:9)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'UnknownEndpoint',
  region: 'us-east-1',
```

But i want to connect to eu-west-3 instead of us-east-1, it seam that my configured region is never picked up.

```
> aws configure list

      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key                <not set>             None    None
secret_key                <not set>             None    None
    region                eu-west-3      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

My ~/.aws/config file :

```
[default]
azure_tenant_id=d8f7***-**-**-9561de6
azure_app_id_uri=https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml
azure_default_username=[my compagnie mail]
azure_default_role_arn=
azure_default_duration_hours=12
azure_default_remember_me=false
region=eu-west-3
    
[profile dev_dom_role]
role_arn=[ my arn role: arn:aws:iam::****:role/dev_dom_role]
source_profile=default
azure_tenant_id=d8f7***-**-**-9561de6
azure_app_id_uri=https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml
azure_default_username=[my compagnie mail]
azure_default_role_arn=[ my arn role: arn:aws:iam::****:role/dev_dom_role]
azure_default_duration_hours=12
azure_default_remember_me=false
```

When i try to configure my profile with `aws-azure-login --configure -p default` every informations is well reconize but unfortunaly it didn't ask for region.

How i connecting ? i try with both role, dev_dom_role and default role :

```
aws-azure-login --mode=gui --profile dev_dom_role
aws-azure-login --mode=gui
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sts.amazonaws.com` was not recognized:

```
nslookup.exe sts.amazonaws.com

Serveur :   ad.intranet.mycompany.fr
Address:  10.10.9.9         

*** ad.intranet.mycompany.com dont find sts.amazonaws.com : Non-existent domain
```

I set the proxy and I was finally able to connect:

```
 PROXY=http://proxy.net:10684
  echo "SET PROXY : " $PROXY
  export http_proxy=$PROXY
  export HTTP_PROXY=$PROXY
  export https_proxy=$PROXY
  export HTTPS_PROXY=$PROXY
  npm config set proxy $PROXY
  npm config set https-proxy $PROXY
  yarn config set proxy $PROXY
  yarn config set https-proxy $PROXY
```